# I need to take a master.txt file and copy all matches into a keyword.txt file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to reduce the amount of work I need to do each day through PHP and am a total novice to righting it, especially when it comes to using patterns and finding matches.

What I need to do is take for example (master.txt)

```
bonsaimimarlik.com,9/28/2013 12:00:00 AM,AUC
imimarlik.com,9/28/2013 12:00:00 AM,AUC
bonsai.com,9/28/2013 12:00:00 AM,AUC
bonsaimimlik.com,9/28/2013 12:00:00 AM,AUC
```

Have it narrow down results to those containing that day's date.
Then strip it down only the domain portion.
Then filter those results down to ones containing keywords I specify in an array.

Once processed down it needs to write everything to a file.

I'm really stuck on the $preq_quote and $preg_match_all portion of this. If you don't want to type out the code, I respect that. I want to learn so if you have anything good I could read on writing out the patterns. My weakest point is not being able to make sense of things like "/^." and "*\%/m" in some of the examples I see.

Answer (score 1):

This will teach  you all the basics  about regular expressions after that you just need to practice to solve your problem

`http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/regular-expressions-for-dummies-screencast-series/`

Have fun learning :)